# Crop picture from camera by code not by user (Create Bitmap)

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I'm trying to crop a picture from camera but it is shown zoomed. the width and height are ok but it's zoomed a lot.

This is my code :

[image: My Code]

Comment: Copy/Paste the code & error as text, rather than uploading a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for scaling bitmaps, the wantedWidth and wantedHeight would be the width and height of your view.

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, new Paint());
    return output;
}
```